# Oracle SQL - Separate Column Into Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with Oracle SQL and have a problem I don't know how to solve.
I have a column in my table that consists of one letter (from a-f) and a number, then another letter (a-f) and another number etc.

Example of column:

```
a 30, d 800, b 233
```

Is there a way where I can separate the column into multiple columns in a select statement?
So that I get ex:

```
TEXTA  NUMBERA  TEXTB  NUMBERB   TEXTD   NUMBERD
  a     30       b      233       d       800
```

Comment: That is not how data should be stored in a relational database - can you change the data model? I assume not... so presumably, if it a-f, there is a maximum of six pairs of values, so you can get a maximum of 12 columns in the final result?

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL for this, but how would you handle the output, given that you don't know in advance how many columns will your query give?

Comment: @AlexPoole you're right, I cannot change the data model. Yes there can be a maximum of 12 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want them as columns like that?

If you do:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^, \s]+', 1, 1)    AS part_1
,       REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^, \s]+', 1, 2)    AS part_2
,       REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^, \s]+', 1, 3)    AS part_3
,       REGEXP_SUBSTR (str, '[^, \s]+', 1, 4)    AS part_4
, ...
FROM    table_x
```

`str` is your column name, `table_x` is your table

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code with the sample data,

```
WITH TEST_DATA AS
(SELECT 'a 30' COLUMN_A,'d 800' COLUMN_B,'b 233' COLUMN_C FROM DUAL)

SELECT SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, 1, INSTR(t.COLUMN_A, ' ')-1) AS TEXTA,
   SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_A, INSTR(t.COLUMN_A, ' ')+1) AS NUMBERA,
   SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_B, 1, INSTR(t.COLUMN_B, ' ')-1) AS TEXTD,
   SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_B, INSTR(t.COLUMN_B, ' ')+1) AS NUMBERD,
   SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_C, 1, INSTR(t.COLUMN_C, ' ')-1) AS TEXTB,
   SUBSTR(t.COLUMN_C, INSTR(t.COLUMN_C, ' ')+1) AS NUMBERB
FROM test_data T;
```

For your reference http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6cff/1